# What is the advantage of typecasting int to long long during calculations?

Tags: c++, casting

I was getting **wrong answer** by the below function.

```
vector<int> repeatedNumber(const vector<int> &A) {
    int n = A.size();
    long long linear_sum = 0,square_sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(;i<n;i++){
        linear_sum += A[i];          //LINE 1
        square_sum += A[i]*A[i];     //LINE 2
    }
    linear_sum = linear_sum - (n*(n+1))/2;
    square_sum = square_sum - (n*(n+1)*(2*n+1))/6;
    square_sum /= linear_sum;
    vector<int> ans;
    ans.push_back((linear_sum+square_sum)/2);
    ans.push_back((-linear_sum+square_sum)/2);
    return ans;
}
```

But when I replaced LINE 1 and LINE 2 with :

```
linear_sum += (long long)A[i];          
square_sum += (long long)A[i]*(long long)A[i];
```

I got the correct answer.Why just typecasting the int to long long solves the problem.

Comment: What was the "wrong" and "right" answers that you were getting?

Comment: Did LINE 1 really need changing?

Comment: The dis-advantage is _assuming_ `long long` will compensate for not insuring various math operations do not overflow.  Better to insure overflow does not happen that simple "use a maybe wider type".

Comment: Should `A` be a `vector<long long>`? Often (but not always) a cast is a sign that the argument should have been of the target type in the first place.

Comment: both versions of line 1 are equivalent

Answer (score 3):

When you multiply two `int` values the result is computed as an `int`.

If the values when multiplied are too big for an `int` you get "undefined behavior" (in most common hardware you just get a seemingly random result).

For example `33554432` (i.e. `1<<25` == 2<sup>25</sup>) is ok for a 32-bit integer, but its square `1125899906842624` (i.e. 2<sup>50</sup>) is not.

Casting to `long long` the terms before computing the multiplication you're hopefully expanding the range in which the computations are done correctly.

These problems are not present in languages that natively provide arbitrary precision integers like Python or Lisp.

Note it's possible that `int` and `long long` are indeed the same size (you can only be sure that a `long long` is not **smaller** than an `int`).

Comment: Casting to `long long` _often_, but not certainly, expands the range.  Depends on complier, etc.

Comment: Typically you won't get a "random" result; usually the high-order bits are discarded. For unsigned types, this behavior is required.

Comment: @KeithThompson: that's why I said "seemingly" :-)

Answer (score 2):

The key is here:

```
A[i]*A[i]
```

This can be too big, overflow the `int`, and only after that, is converted to `long long`, but.

```
(long long)A[i]*(long long)A[i];
```

is first converted and then multiply and may not overflow the `long long`